# Method for calculating minimum number of transmissions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization

(This is a real issue I face.)

I have $42$ files I want to transmit.  I tried sending them in a single archive but four of them had issues, and as a result the entire archive was rejected.  I do know that four files were bad for some reason, but the error message doesn't tell me which ones.  Sending these files is slow all around:  time-consuming up front, and with a lag.

The help desk guy recommended sending them ten at a time, but then gave that second thoughts, saying, "Yeah, but it could be that there's one bad file in each one, and none would get through."

I agree it should be something less, like three at a time:  $14$ batches of $3$ files mean that at most $12$ files are rejected at the end.

Then I can resend those $12$ files one at a time, and I've saved myself at least $42-(14+12) = 16$ transmissions, and I now know which ones are bad so I can track down why.

My question is whether there's a framework/method that lets me figure out the optimal number of transmissions.  Given $b$ bad files from $n$ files, how do I minimize the number of transmissions to pick out the bad ones?

Comment: From a practical standpoint, have you considered just sending all 42 files individually to see which ones break things?

Comment: @McFry That would work for sure.  At some point I may need to send $500$ files, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an exact analogy between your situation and the problem of pooling lab samples to test for the presence of disease, where disease occurrence is relatively rare and it's costly to run each test. See, for example, the first page of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.4903.pdf for the determination of optimal pool size and therefore the number of tests to run.

Comment: Fascinating that there's an analogy between a kludgy file transfer system and HIV testing!